# Sourcing or creating (using PHP), a lists of all countries and their relevant ISO codes?

Tags: php, iso

I'm hoping that someone could help me find a complete list of all countries and their relevant ISO codes. More precisely, I need:

```
ISO 4217, ISO 3166-1, ISO 639-1, country name
```

Example:

```
EUR, IE, en, Ireland
```

Everything I find seems to be in bit's and pieces. I could spend a lot of time fixing it all together but I was hoping that someone would know; either a way to programmatically create the list through PHP or know of a place where this has already been done?

Most relevant sources already visited:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1
- http://www.fincher.org/Utilities/CountryLanguageList.shtml

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a programming question, you may have better luck on [Open Data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a php array of the [ISO 3166-1 alpha 2 country codes](https://gist.github.com/vxnick/380904).

Comment: Thanks Jon, I was hoping to have an array that contained everything but it's a good start :).